# Trying to understand groupby() and sum() in pandas

Tags: pandas

My understanding on groupby() was that the chosen column act as an index to group the rest of columns.

So if I have

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 3],[3, 1, 1],[3, 0, 0],[2, 3, 3],[2, 1, 0]], columns=list('xyz'))
gby = df.groupby('x')

df:
   x  y  z
0  0  1  3
1  3  1  1
2  3  0  0
3  2  3  3
4  2  1  0
```

and my conceptual model of groupby result is

```
  y z
x 
0 1 3
2 3 3
  1 0
3 1 1
  0 0
```

where columns are [y,z] and x is an index.

So if I perform

```
ap = gby.apply(pd.DataFrame.sum)
```

I would expect the return to be

```
    y  z
x 
0   1  3
2   4  3
3   1  1
```

instead it returns

```
x         
0  0  1  3
2  4  4  3
3  6  1  1
```

where column x is still included in the dataframe, could anyone explain what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

> where column x is still included in the dataframe, could anyone explain what I am missing?

I think it is expected, because [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) working with all columns, so if use `pd.DataFrame.sum` it create new column `x` and also convert `x` to index:

```
def f(x):
    print (x)
    print (x.sum())
    return x.sum()

   x  y  z
0  0  1  3
x    0
y    1
z    3
dtype: int64
   x  y  z
3  2  3  3
4  2  1  0
x    4
y    4
z    3
dtype: int64
   x  y  z
1  3  1  1
2  3  0  0
x    6
y    1
z    1
dtype: int64

ap = gby.apply(f)
print (ap)
   x  y  z
x         
0  0  1  3
2  4  4  3
3  6  1  1
```

If use `sum` function by default omit columns used for grouping - only set `x` to index:

```
ap = gby.sum()
print (ap)
   y  z
x      
0  1  3
2  4  3
3  1  1
```

But if explicitely specify columns for sum after `groupby` it is not excluded:

```
ap = gby['x','y','z'].sum()
print (ap)
   x  y  z
x         
0  0  1  3
2  4  4  3
3  6  1  1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess my confusion is that the x column in this case becomes an index column, and apply() wouldn't perform on index column. Am I still misunderstanding?

Comment: @user3562812 - I added better sample of `apply` - here `groupby` convert `x` to index but also sum `x` values, because `apply` working with all columns `x,y,z`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess my confusion till now was that x was no longer a column in groupby, so apply() will not consider x as a column.

Answer (score 1):

Completely logical.

`df.groupby('x')` has three groups: x=0, x=2 and x=3 (the distinct values for x).

When you aggregate with `sum()` you get the totals for `y` and `z` within each of these 3 groups.